# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied windows application

Tags: winforms

I have some code to call the exe with below code

```
Process vasontCall = new Process();
vasontCall.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Name.exe";
vasontCall.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
vasontCall.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
vasontCall.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
vasontCall.Start();
```

in one of our client is getting the below error, 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at Sysotem.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Client confirms that he has Administrator permission, what are possible reason and how to overcome this.

Comment: Why do you have UseShellExecute = true there? Anyway, you should specify what is accessing what when the Name.exe executable is run. Is the executable something you produced or a 3rd party's?

Comment: yes its 3rd party component